# Is there any extensions i haven't installed yet?

Tags: reactjs

I am a 2nd year college student and i wanted to learn how to create a website, but i have this problem:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTZK8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTZK8.png)
the  part doesn't work, i have a .jsx file that has the same name. The yt video that I'm also watching is like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHwWM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHwWM.png)
but his Navbar does work. Any Ideas?

I'm tried installing recommended extensions such as snippets and auto import and other stuff but it still doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Navbar is a custom component made, if you look at your 3rd screenshot it says it is imported. It has to exist before you can create it.

Also for future reference, please post your code in the proper format and not to another website! When you create a post it displays the format you should use.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time posting here, i just realized that i haven't imported it yet on my App.js. It works now

Comment: @JayD glad everything worked out. Welcome to Stackoverflow! Also if my answer suited you please mark it as correct!